# How can I dynamically add a URL into javascript, to get a second page's div to display on the first page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic, load

Ok, so this what I have that works, for the starting code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.currentpagediv').load('http://theurl.com/page2/somethingsomewhere.html .secondpagedivclass');
});
```

What this does, is find the div on the current page, `<div class="currentpagediv">`, and add in the second page (`http://theurl.com/page2/somethingsomewhere.html`) div `<div class="secondpagedivclass">`

So for example, say I have a page like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="currentpagediv">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

then what my code above does is make this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="currentpagediv">
    </div>
    <div class="secondpagedivclass">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Which is just what I want it to do. So I have the functionality I need.

BUT, the problem is that I need the URL portion to be ***dynamic***.
For example, the current page is always `http://theurl.com/page1/[a path].html`, and the new page that I need to fetch the div is always `http://theurl.com/page2/[the same path].html`

So basically, I need to get the URL, and change ONLY `/page1/` to `/page2/`, while retaining this. That way I can run on all the pages of the domain and it will add the section from `page2` into `page1`.

Like this:

---

Original page `http://theurl.com/page1/365743668.html`:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="currentpagediv">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Second page `http://theurl.com/page2/365743668.html`:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="secondpagedivclass">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**NEW ORIGINAL PAGE THAT THE SCRIPT IS RUNNING ON (still `http://theurl.com/page1/365743668.html`):**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="currentpagediv">
    </div>
    <div class="secondpagedivclass">
       [THE INFO FROM PAGE `http://theurl.com/page2/365743668.html`]
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've tried many things, but they did not work.

Here is my attempt which does not work:

---

```
function changeURL() {
        var theURL = location.pathname.toString();
        var newURL = theURL.replace("/page1/", "/page2/");
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.currentpagediv').load(changeURL() '.secondpagedivclass');
});
```

In the code above, I tried to:

1. fetch the url of current page
2. convert the url to a string, so I could
3. modify the url, and then
4. add the function `changeURL()` in place of where the URL went after `.load('`

---

Please note I want to make it work using **jquery** and **this method** (NOT ANOTHER METHOD) because I'm also trying to learn, and giving me something completely different is not going to help me learn how to do this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just missing the string concatenation operation, `+`.

```
$('.currentpagediv').load(changeURL() + ' .secondpagedivclass');
```

Don't forget the space before `.secondpagedivclass`.

The `changeURL` function needs to return the result:

```
function changeURL() {
    var theURL = location.pathname;
    var newURL = theURL.replace("/page1/", "/page2/");
    return newURL;
}
```

You don't need to use `.toString()`, since the pathname is a string.

Comment: Great, only thing:
`function changeURL() {
  var theURL = location.pathname.toString();
  theURL.replace("/page1/", "/page2/");
  return;
}` is my code, but I only get this URL instead of the new URL: `http://theurl.com/page1/undefined`

Comment: I voted you up because it seems that part is right, but I also need to fix the `changeURL()` function so it works. Once that works I will choose as best answer!