# How can I append "?new_page=2" to a URL within javascript? It seems the question mark isn't allowing me to parse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic, load

My original code which works is this:

```
function changeURL() {
    var theURL = location.pathname;
    var newURL = theURL.replace("/page1/", "/page2/");
    return newURL;
}

$('.currentpagediv').load(changeURL() + ' .secondpagedivclass');
```

Basically, per [How can I dynamically add a URL into javascript, to get a second page's div to display on the first page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753776/how-can-i-dynamically-add-a-url-into-javascript-to-get-a-second-pages-div-to-d/25753833#25753833), I am trying to add new content from second page into the first page.

However, Now I am trying to also add the SECOND PAGE of the second page into the first page, because the way it is set up, it shows page 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc pagination at the bottom. I am trying to also show the other pages in the same page.

For example,

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="currentpagediv">
    </div>
    <div class="secondpagedivclass">
      [CONTENT HERE]
      Page 2, Page 3, Page 4, etc.
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But I want:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="currentpagediv">
    </div>
    <div class="secondpagedivclass">
      [CONTENT HERE]
      [Page 2 Pagination Link CONTENT HERE]
      [Page 3 Pagination Link CONTENT HERE]
      [Page 4 Pagination Link CONTENT HERE]
      [etc.]
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Original URL that I am inserting, looks like this:
http://theurl.com/page2/somethingsomewhere.html

The pagination pages look like this:
http://theurl.com/page2/somethingsomewhere.html?new_page=2
http://theurl.com/page2/somethingsomewhere.html?new_page=3
etc.

---

Here is the code I tried first that does not work:

```
$('.currentpagediv').load(changeURL() + ' .secondpagedivclass' + '?new_page=2');
```

But I learned it does not work because you can't parse the question mark. I read that instead I should use `.search` to parse the new page. So I tried this:

```
function changeURL() {
        var theURL = location.pathname;
        var newURL = theURL.replace("/page1/", "/page2/");
        return newURL;
}

function secondPage() {
        var secondURL = changeURL()
        var secondnewURL = secondURL.search('new_page', 2);
        return secondnewURL;
}

$('.currentpagediv').load(secondPage() + ' .secondpagedivclass');
```

In the above code, the only difference from the original working code is the addition of the `secondPage()` function, and adding that function after `.load(`.

In the code above, I tried to:

1. fetch the url of current page
2. modify the url, and then
3. append `?new_page=2` to the end of the new url, and
4. add the function secondPage() to create the URL

Comment: The `?` is a special character in regular expressions.  `\?` should do it for you.

Comment: It worked! Thank you also I think I put it in the wrong place which is why it did not work the fist time. Instead I needed to include it after `.load(changeURL()`, not at the end. I had tried to escape it but before I put it in the wrong place. What worked was this: `$('.currentpagediv').load(changeURL() + '\?not_recommended_start=10' + ' .secondpagedivclass');

Comment: too bad I can't accept as best answer since you didn't post this as an answer.